# Problems with visualization symbols in shp layer with QGIS 3.28

Tags: scale, symbols, qgis

I have a polygon shapefile with two objects (two multypolygons) that somebody sent me, with its qml and qmd.

The problem is that when I change the scale, depending on the side of the polygon, below 1:X.000 one of the polygons dissapear.

I try to eliminate the qml and qmd associated; I save as a new shp or kml; I searched in the properties of the layer and symbol properties; I try to add a new style; I set a new scale visualization option. Nothing of this works.